# Add UNION between sqls of queries are not empty

Tags: php, sql

I all. I have an array of queries

```
$queries = [
    $sql1,
    $sql2,
    $sql3,
    $sql4
];
```

I want a PHP function that can automatically concatenate 'UNION' between them. For example if all 4 queries are there, it should return something like

```
$sql1 . ' UNION ' . $sql2 . ' UNION ' . $sql3 . ' UNION ' . $sql4;
```

If `$sql2` and `$sql3` are empty, it should return

```
$sql1 . ' UNION ' . $sql4
```

Currently I am using this function

```
function concatenate_queries($arr){
    $final_query = "";
    foreach ($arr as $q){
        $final_query = $q . ' UNION ';
    }
    return $final_query;
}
```

But it does not produce correct output.

**EDIT**

Sample of queries

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => SELECT 'deposit' as t_type, tx_amount as total, tx_fee as fee, tx_net as amount, tx_currency as currency, tx_exchange_rate as ex_rate, transactionTime as created , paymentId as trax_id,  'payments' as tb, 'completed' as status  FROM payments WHERE userId='51' AND (DATE(transactionTime) BETWEEN '2018-08-24' AND '2018-09-24')
UNION
SELECT 'deposit' as t_type, amount as total, 0 as fee, amount as amount, 'EUR' as currency, 1 as ex_rate,  created, id as trax_id,  'coinbase_deposits' as tb, 'completed' as status FROM coinbase_deposits WHERE asset='EUR' AND userId='51' AND (DATE(created) BETWEEN '2018-08-24' AND '2018-09-24')

    [1] => SELECT 'buy' as t_type, total_amount as total, fee_coinbase as fee, subtotal as amount, total_amount_currency as currency, 1 as ex_rate,  created, id as trax_id, 'coinbase_transactions' as tb,status FROM coinbase_transactions
WHERE wallet='EUR' AND userId='51' AND resource='sell' AND (DATE(created) BETWEEN '2018-08-24' AND '2018-09-24') 

    [2] => SELECT 'withdraw' as t_type, amount as total, 0 as fee, amount, 'gbp' as currency , 1 as ex_rate, created, id as trax_id, 'refunds' as tb, 'completed' as status FROM refunds WHERE user_id='51' AND (DATE(created) BETWEEN '2018-08-24' AND '2018-09-24') 
UNION
 SELECT 'withdraw' as t_type, amount as total_amount, 0 as fee, amount,  'gbp' as currency , 1 as ex_rate, created, id as trax_id, 'manual_refunds' as tb,  CASE WHEN (status=0) THEN 'pending' ELSE 'completed' END as status FROM manual_refunds WHERE user_id='51' AND (DATE(created) BETWEEN '2018-08-24' AND '2018-09-24
    [3] => SELECT 'sell' as t_type, total_amount as total, fee_coinbase as fee, subtotal as amount, total_amount_currency as currency, 1 as ex_rate, created , id as trax_id, 'coinbase_transactions' as tb, status FROM coinbase_transactions WHERE wallet='EUR' AND userId='51' AND resource='buy' AND (DATE(created) BETWEEN '2018-08-24' AND '2018-09-24')

)
</pre>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the queries, it may be better to try and add the conditions to 1 query than union several results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)?

```
$final_query = implode(' UNION ', array_filter($queries));
```

Comment: @AliZia If there can be empty queries in the array, you may want to pass it through `array_filter` like this: `$final_query = implode(' UNION ', array_filter($queries));`. For a next time, please make sure that important specifications like that are in the question from the start, and are reflected in the example you give.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it you way you will have a UNION after the last line of code, so you get
sql1 UNION sql2 UNION sql3 UNION sql4 UNION. This will fail.

You could do something like this:

```
function concatenate_queries($arr){
    $final_query = "";
    $union = "";
    foreach ($arr as $q){
        $final_query .= $union . $q;
        $union = ' UNION ';
    }
    return $final_query;
}
```

This way you will have sql1 UNION sql2 UNION sql3 UNION sql4

EDIT: Fabric's way is more efficient, just use implode().

Comment: `$union` is an empty string in the first cycle. Also, there's no point to redefine it in every loop.

Comment: `$final_query = $union . $q;` should be `$final_query .= ...`

Comment: @fabrik Thats totally intended that `$union` is an empty string in the first cycle, otherwise you'd get `UNION sql1 UNION sql2` which doesnt make sense of course, you want `sql1 UNION sql2`

Comment: @Xatenev, you are right, I edited it, that's what you get for lazy copying :P

Comment: Yes, you're right I've overlooked that, sorry for that :)